# EF with Inheritance with concrete classes

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I have set of entities with some level of inheritance.

```
abstract class A
{
...
}

class B: A //Non abstract B
{...}

class C : B //Non abstract C
```

Since B and C are concrete classes i 
I tried setting up TPC inheritance strategy to get tables for B and C concrete classes in the database. However, because i did MapInheritedProperties() on B and C I get columns from table A duplicated in table C. How do i stop this? Am i using right inheritance strategy? Also, when i save changes to C(only) entity framework creates a row in table B for a row in C. Is there a way to prevent this? I don't see anything wrong with my inheritance. 
Another approach which i tried is getting rid of the inheritance and use TPT for B and C and used Navigation property to link B and C. This approach worked but i am not convinced on why first approach didn't work.